# Connecting to SQL when MSI Enabled

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I have an App Service that connect to an Azure SQL. The App Service and Azure SQL is stored in same resource group and I already enabled MSI and I already provided access in SQL for the Azure AD Group that was created. In my code when I tried to open a conenction to the sql. I get the following error

Cannot open server "[servername]" requested by the login. The login failed.

I can see that I am getting an access token

Comment: Can you confirm that you've done everything detailed here: [*Secure Azure SQL Database connection from App Service using a managed identity*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)?

Comment: Have you added the MSI(service principal) to the AD group?

Comment: @JoyWang yes I already added my principal ID to my AAD group. And the AAD group already has Read and Write permission to my SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Azure App service in your Azure SQL in access control (IAM).

Navigate to your Azure SQL and locate Access Control(IAM). On IAM, click on add role assignment and Provide Role as 'Contributor' and Principal as 'Your App Service'. Save the changes.

Now app service will be able to Authenticate itself to SQL database.

Comment: ill try later Thanks

Comment: I am currently in process of giving my Application ID access to my Azure SQL. Unfortunately other department are handling Azure Admin side

Comment: Yes! It requires Admin Access to Add the roles in IAM.

Comment: Who should I provide role or permission in the SQL Server in IAM? is it the Azure AD Group or the WebApp?

Comment: @Billy, it has to be Web App.

Comment: Ok ill advise our admin and give it a try. Thanks Anish